# Update newly added column with value on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to move a column from one table to the other without loosing the data .Can I copy the data to the column in new table without creating any copy/temporary table of the original table.

Comment: If you already removed it then it's gone, or else use present tense instead of past tense. Apart from that: always show us what you tried, which should at least include an UPDATE query.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ...when i read my question for the second time same has raised in mind also..Thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that using the following query.

```
UPDATE SchemeMember
SET personID = b.personUID
FROM SchemeMember s,benefit b
WHERE s.Id = b.SchemeMemberId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't removed the `PersonID`column from `benefit` table,
use the below script to update the newly added column in `SchemeMember` table

```
   UPDATE c
    SET c.personID =b.personID 
   FROM benefit b
      JOIN SchemeMember c on b.SchemeMemberID  =c.SchemeMemberID
```

Comment: Thanks Unni krishanan

Comment: Mark as right answer,if the solution resolved your query.